# Account restrictions

Tags: support, post-ban

I recently got a message when I tried to reply saying that my account could no longer submit answers. When I looked at why, I saw the reasons for why this may have happened. I didn’t think I had done any of the reasons, so does anyone have a suggestion? Please help me on this.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: I see 4 answers on your profile with a total net score of -1, which shouldn't be enough to trigger an answer ban. This makes me think that there are deleted posts on that your account that are also counting as negative marks against you. Could a moderator/experienced user confirm or refute this please?

Comment: There are a number of deleted answers, yes, and deleted answers do still count towards the answer ban. The list is visible to @Hahacornflakes and moderators on this page: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/265731

Answer (score 3):

I dont want to come off as rude but, you did do those things.

Let me go through some answers you made:

- [My horse can't be leashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382176/247794)

  - Your solution wouldn't work with the given situation
  - Your answer didn't really add anything to the existing answers
- [Does destroying a chest in a bastion remnant anger piglins?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382173/247794)

  - You didn't even answer the question, the user wasn't asking about piglin brutes.
  - You also demonstrated a very limited understanding of the game
- [What is the quickest way to kill a wither in minecraft!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382171/247794)

  - You said you haven't even tried it
  - Again demonstrated lack of knowledge
  - You cant build above nether roof in bedrock

and your questions were not perfect either, you posted this originally in the wrong place

The first thing you can do is fix these answers, maybe test out the ones you were unsure of or do research on what you can do in versions. **DONT** delete your bad answers and question. Refer to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/729167) for more info on what to do.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about that

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 ah, sorry let me fix that